# How to collect all values from hashtable without its keys

Tags: java, hashtable

i have a merged hash table and it is having around 4351 distinct keys and its relevant values,but i don't want to specify its each and every key for fetching values,i want to directly collect all the values only, how do i handle this?

Note:all the values are distinct 100% ,thats why i want to fetch blindly those data for further process

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [`Hashtable#values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#values%28%29):

```
public Collection<V> values()
```

> Returns a Collection view of the values
>   contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so changes
>   to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa. If the map
>   is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress
>   (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of
>   the iteration are undefined. The collection supports element removal,
>   which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the
>   Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear
>   operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.
>
> **Specified by:**
>   values in interface Map
>   **Returns:**
> a collection view of the values contained in this map
> **Since:**
>   1.2

Comment: hi Fouad, by <tashtable_name>.values() am able to see the values,how to assign those values to another vector/variable

Comment: `Collection<TypeOfYourValues> variable = yourHashTable.values();`

Comment: Vector v= new vector(); v.add all(hash table.values());

Answer (score 0):

you can collect all the Values in a ArrayList Eg:

if you have like

```
   HashTable <Object,Type> hm;
```

then you can use

```
   ArrayList<Type> al= new ArrayList<Type>(hm.values());
```

all your values are now inside array list